# Revelation 21:5 - “Behold, I am making all things new?”

Tags: revelation, grammar, creation, john-the-revelator, eschatology

In Revelation 21:5, when God says

> ***"Behold, I am making all things new.”***

It seems straightforward to me that God is making all things (in the main or on the whole if not all individual things) that had previously existed to become new.

From a pure Greek grammar standpoint Is this understanding so straightforwardly drawn from the text? Is the statement, ***“Behold, I am making all things new”*** actually ambiguous and could be understood as God is *making* *all new things* instead of God *making the old to become new.*

Alternatively, does the grammar only allow one way to understand the line ***“Behold, I am making all things new?”***

Comment: Literally it is "You see ... brand-new ... I make ... all".

Comment: @MikeBorden, True, but does "all" relate to things that are previously existed or does "all" refer to brand new things that previously did not exist. Does the grammar accommodate either view?

Answer (score 3):

Grammatically, the phrase: καινὰ ποιῶ πάντα (= new I make all) could be translated as any of the following:

1. I make all new things (ie, start all over again)
2. I make all things new [again]

Before proceeding, let us be very clear about the implications of each translation:

1. In translation #1, "I make all new things" suggests that all created things will be re-created and thus, there is no connection to what went before.  This necessarily includes people and our planet, etc.  This means that when God makes all new things, we, as forgiven sinners, will NOT be part of the new creation.
2. In translation #2, "I make all things new" implies that all the old things are being refreshed and made better, including sinners.

Indeed, the latter sense in what is discussed extensively in 1 Cor 15:35-49 predicts the time when we will all receive new resurrections bodies.  Other explicit cases of when things will be renewed (from BDAG):

- New Covenant, is something new but clearly based on the old covenant, Matt 26:28, Mark 14:24, Luke 22:20, 1 Cor 11:25, 23 Cor 3:6, Heb 8:8, 13, 9:15.
- New heaven and New earth, 2 Peter 3:13, Rev 21:1, see also
- New Jerusalem, Rev 21:2, 3:12
- New drink in the kingdom, Matt 26:29, Mark 14:25
- New (converted person), Eph 4:24, 2 Cor 5:17, Gal 6:15, Eph 2:15.

Answer (score 2):

Everything in the NT is the fulfillment (ala *[Sensus Plenior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensus_plenior)*) of something in the OT. The only safe way to interpret any passage in the NT is by locating what it is intended to fulfil from the OT. In this case it is fairly easy to identify the prophetic passages:

> [Isaiah 42:9 NKJV] **(9) Behold, the former things have come to pass, And new things I declare; Before they spring forth I tell you of them."**

> [Isaiah 42:9 LXX] (9) τὰ ἀπ᾽ ἀρχῆς ἰδοὺ ἥκασιν καὶ καινὰ ἃ ἐγὼ ἀναγγελῶ καὶ πρὸ τοῦ ἀνατεῗλαι ἐδηλώθη ὑμῗν

> [Isaiah 48:5-8 NKJV] (5) Even from the beginning I have declared [it] to you; **Before it came to pass I proclaimed [it] to you,** Lest you should say, 'My idol has done them, And my carved image and my molded image Have commanded them.' (6) "You have heard; See all this. And will you not declare [it]? I have made you hear new things from this time, Even hidden things, and you did not know them. **(7) They are created now and not from the beginning; And before this day you have not heard them, Lest you should say, 'Of course I knew them.' (8) Surely you did not hear, Surely you did not know; Surely from long ago your ear was not opened.** For I knew that you would deal very treacherously, And were called a transgressor from the womb.

So I think the idea seems to be all new things, not all things new.

Unless I'm mistaken, [καινός](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%B9%CE%BD%E1%BD%B9%CF%82) would not be the adjective to use for a modification.

Answer (score 1):

> "Therefore if any man be in Christ, he is a new creature: old things are passed away; behold, all things are become new." - 2 Cor 5:17 KJV

> "For I will be merciful to their unrighteousness, and their sins and their iniquities will I remember no more. In that he saith, A new covenant, he hath made the first old. Now that which decayeth and waxeth old is ready to vanish away." - Heb 8:12-13 KJV

There is a clear cross reference with the concept illustrated in 2 Cor 5:17. And from Heb 8:13 we see the concept of "new" vs. "old" to mean a passing or vanishing of what was. There is a theme present with the fulfilment of the intentions pointed to by the old that can only be achieved by renewal. The sense of this "I make things new" can interpreted through the concept of regeneration or being "born again" per 1 Pet 1:23.

> "Being born again, not of corruptible seed, but of incorruptible, by the word of God, which liveth and abideth for ever." - 1 Pet 1:23

The Rev 21 scene includes imagery of old earth & heaven passing away and new earth & heaven appearing.

The clear context based on the surrounding texts points to renewal rather than something formed ex nihilio or from complete annihilation.

If we look at the Greek used for "make" in Rev 21:5, the same form of the word appears in Mat 21:24-27 where it is translated as "do". The Greek word for "new" in Rev 21:5 can also be translated in the sense of "freshen" ("fresh" from Strong's 2537) and it is the same word used in 2 Cor 5:17. From this sense, that part of Rev 21:5 could be translated to emphasize the sense of "I do freshen everything."

Even if you could concievable translate Rev 21:5 in isolation to convey "I make everything from scratch" that sense would not be consistent with the overall exegetic. If we have combinations of possible contexts from different parts of the same body of texts, a useful convention is to give the most consideration for possible interpretations of each part that yields the most holistic cohesion and coherency. It may be the case that either sense of "make new" could be possible, but given a convention of interpretation that favours noncontradiction where possible, "make new" in the sense of "renewal" or "regeneration" is the most compelling.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Very thought-provoking. How does "do" improve on the translation of "make?" It is not obvious, from your answer alone,  that it does improve it. Also, on what basis do you claim that "new" can be translated as "freshen?" I haven't been able to locate a resource that would corroborate that statement. Lastly, it doesn't seem like your response specifically answers my question about whether or not the grammar of Rev 21:5 could accommodate multiple interpretations or not. Thanks, again. I found the scripture references overall helpful to my spiritual ponderings.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I would contend that "I do freshen" would be a valid translation but not an improvement.

Comment: I'm not a Greek expert but it would follow that even if it is possible for a passage to be translated two ways, if one of the possible translations causes a contradiction with the rest of the text, it should be considered less compelling than a possible translation that is consistent. I would contend that a holistic approach should be considered preferentially in translation. We see this convention used when the capitalization of "God" is determined from the source Greek manuscripts (as the manuscripts don't show the capitalization). That capitalization is determined within a holistic context.

Answer (score 1):

It is a *renewal* not a throwing away of the old and replacing it with something with no connection to what has been thrown away. However it should be viewed in the same sense as we get new, glorified bodies to replace the old bodies. A new earth to replace the old earth, etc. This is also called a "regeneration" in Matthew:

Matthew 19:28 (KJV 1900)

> And Jesus said unto them, Verily I say unto you, That ye which have
> followed me, in the **regeneration when the Son of man shall sit in the
> throne of his glory**, ye also shall sit upon twelve thrones, judging
> the twelve tribes of Israel.

regeneration = παλιγγενεσία, whose BDAG entry refers to this passage:
*of the renewing of the world in the time of the Messiah, an eschatol. sense (Schürer II 537f; Bousset, Rel.3 280ff) ἐν τῇ παλ. in the new (Messianic) age or world Mt 19:28.*

It is the same word that Paul uses in Titus:

Titus 3:5 (KJV 1900)

> Not by works of righteousness which we have done, but according to
> his mercy he saved us, by the washing of **regeneration**, and renewing of
> the Holy Ghost;

Therefore when John sees Christ *sitting on the throne*:

Revelation 21:5 (KJV 1900)

> And he that sat upon the throne said, Behold, *I make all things new* (καινὰ ποιῶ πάντα).
> And he said unto me, Write: for these words are true and faithful.

We can be sure that this is an allusion to the previous passage in Matthew, which speaks of regeneration of the fallen world, and the same regeneration that happens in the believer (see below).

We also see this promise in Paul's writings, of the renewal of all creation, including ourselves:

Romans 8:19–23 (KJV 1900)

> For the earnest expectation of the creature waiteth for the
> manifestation of the sons of God.
>
> For the creature was made subject
> to vanity, not willingly, but by reason of him who hath subjected the
> same in hope,
>
> Because the creature itself also shall be delivered
> from the bondage of corruption into the glorious liberty of the
> children of God.
>
> For we know that the whole creation groaneth and
> travaileth in pain together until now.
>
> And not only they, but
> ourselves also, which have the firstfruits of the Spirit, even we
> ourselves groan within ourselves, waiting for the adoption, to wit,
> the redemption of our body.

So the promise of renewal is the same as the promise of salvation:

2 Corinthians 5:17 (KJV 1900)

> Therefore if any man be in Christ, he is a new creature: old things
> are passed away; behold, **all things are become new** (ἰδοὺ γέγονεν καινά).

Comment: Very fine response. I always enjoy your contributions, even if it doesn't fully answer my question which is primarily about grammar. You caught my attention saying, *"when John sees Christ sitting on the throne,"* in reference to verse 5. Is it your view that, in the resurrection, we will be the children of Jesus, as verse 7 indicates if your referent is correct?

Comment: Thanks @Austin. For verse 7, I think "I will be his God and he shall be my son" has to be understood in the semitic sense of "son", which just means group membership. E.g. "sons of worthelessness" to denote a worthless person or "son of Amalek" to denote a member of the tribe. Thus "I will be his God" is the same statement as "he shall be my son", just from different perspectives.